# Нужен легкий WYSIWIG редактор и серверная часть от него

Tags: wysiwyg, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени, нужен легкий js редактор, который цепляется за textarea и добавляет свой функционал - такой же как на этом сайте.

Пербрал уже десяток редакторов - во всех, если скопировать текст на странице и вставить в окно редактора появляется куча левого кода, который потом чтоб прочистить надо умом тронуться.

Надо чтоб была работа с тегами `<a><b><i><u><i><sub><sup><strike><font><span><br>` и серверная часть на PHP, которая, после отправки POST хорошо расфильтрует это дело и очистит от возможных инъекций. Или только качественный класс с фильтрами, который можно самому настроить для того, чтоб профильтровать данные отправленные редактором на стороне сервера.

Подскажите рабочую демку или куда смотреть хотя бы.. сутки убиты, решения нормального не нашел.
Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: TinyMCE чем Вас не устроил?

Comment: @trans, в дополнение к комментарию @t0di, про защиту от инъекций говорилось миллион раз. Используйте поиск по сайту

Comment: это не инъекция, а xss

Answer (score 5):

[Imperavi](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) всем рекомендую его. Собственно и тема на форуме уже была подобная

Comment: ниче редактор, спасибо

Comment: Imperavi пробовал, он у меня не работает - что то с вязанное с вызовом модальных окон пересекается с уже установленными скриптами и в этот редактор всё равно не подходит. Спасибо @pavelbel - его редактор гасит все лишние коды на этапе вставки - буду использовать его.

Comment: спасибо, ничего такой...

Comment: Если пересекается значит дело просто в ID элементов

>$(function()
>{  $('#redactor_content').redactor({ fixed: true }); 
>});
><textarea id="redactor_content" name="content" ">
></textarea>

Ведь вставка его на страницу простая, с чем сложности?

Comment: нет не в ID, у меня стоят скрипты вызова модальных окон, в которых видимо, пересекаются имена функций или глобальных переменных из-за этого не работает скрипт Imperavi. Возиться с этим смысла нет т.к. редактор меня изначально не устраивает из-за того что все теги во вставляемом тексте принимает как родные, а мне надо чтоб всё вычищалось.

Comment: Тогда вопрос нафига тебе редактор если для тебя textarea будет в самый раз?
Если тебе не нужны теги, нафига html редактор на сайте?


Исходя из выше написанного -  вопрос задан некорректно!

Comment: Понравился, купил. Но такое ощущение, что его русские писали - напильником обрабатывать и обрабатывать...) Не удивительно, что разработчики так по миру бегают... )

Comment: сразу стоит отметить что его минимальная цена $99 (это если ты для себя берешь) если кому то пишешь то сразу еще $100 добавляйте

Answer (score 0):

[elRte](http://elrte.org/ru/) - бесплатный, сделанный нашими соотечественниками([демка](http://elrte.org/ru/demo)) + к нему есть отличный [elFinder](http://elfinder.org/), такой же бесплатный :)

Пользуюсь только этими инструментами, если нужен WYSIWIG

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрый человек за наводку! Если подскажешь класс или набор фильтров, чтоб безопасно сохранить полученные из редактора данные - цены тебе не сложу )

К сожалению у этого редакатора, как и у десятка других, которые перебрал есть основной (в моем случае) недостаток - если копирую содержимое произвольной страницы и вставляю в редактор, то вся верстка, стили и оформление тоже переносятся... а потом на стороне сервера надо както эту всю хрень прочистить, причем после чистки и сохранения пользователь увидит совершенно не то, что отправлял из формы...

Comment: Желательно, чтоб после вставки в редактор остались только теги: <a><b><i><u><i><sub><sup><strike><font><span><br> (или была возможность управлять набором допустимых тегов), все стили, блоки и таблицы потерты и остался контент с допустимыми тегами (как это происходит при обычной вставке в textarea, но там вообще никаких тегов не остается)

Comment: Если рассматриваете как вариант BB-коды, понравился http://www.wysibb.com тоже свой человек работает, простой как валенок и тем самым хорош

Comment: Спасибо - именно то, что нужно!

Comment: @pavelbel можете подсказать класс или набор функций для чистки данных поступивших из bb-редактора перед сохранением в базу?

Comment: Поскольку пишу на Ruby, использую bb-ruby (https://github.com/cpjolicoeur/bb-ruby), а вообще, можно прям bb-код в базе хранить и с помощью методов редактора конвертировать текст туда-сюда, при рендеринге